# Change LLVM Xray instructions during runtime

Tags: clang, llvm

Is it possible to change the "always instrument" to "never instrument" while running a program? By that, I mean, is it possible to change attributes and expect Xray to run without recompiling the program?

Comment: Could you give more information about what options you use to compile and run a certain program?

Comment: The LLVM guide says it is possible to change the status of instrumentations using the xray_instr_map, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM guide says it is possible to change the status of instrumentations using the xray_instr_map, but I'm not sure how to use it.